# jquery jcarousel with "circular" config

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

so im using the jcarousel with :

```
      wrap:"circular",
      itemFirstInCallback: {
 onBeforeAnimation: callback1,
 onAfterAnimation: callback2
}
```

what i want is to have the i incrementer increment or decrement but in a concise manner!

for example if the carousel length is 10 (are we're pressing the next button) when the i arrives to 10 its next value should be 1(as we're now on item 1 of the carousel)
another example: if we're pressing the prev button and i value is 1 its next value should be 10(as we're now on last carousel element)

so i am not able to have this behavior, i tried this (using the onAfterAnimation callbak):

```
function callback2 (carousel, item, i, state){
       if(state=="next"){
        if(i==carousel.size()+1) {
         i=1
        } else{
        }
            alert(i);
       }
              if(state=="prev"){
              if(i==0) {
          i=carousel.size()
        }
            alert(i);
       }
}
```

but i still dont get a concise incrementor/decrementor

Answer (score 0):

```
if(i==carousel.size()+1)
```

should be

```
if(i==carousel.size()-1)
```

since you're using an 0 based index on i (based on `if(state==prev) if (i==0)`

Comment: carousel.size() starts at 1, im just trying to hack the carousel to get a concise incrementor/decrementor